# Why nested FlexLayout is not visible in this case?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlexLayout2"
             x:Class="FlexLayout2.MainPage">

    <FlexLayout
        Direction="Column"
        JustifyContent="Start"
        AlignItems="Stretch">
        <FlexLayout
            Direction="Row"
            JustifyContent="Start"
            AlignItems="Stretch">
            <BoxView Color="Red"/>
            <BoxView Color="Black"/>
        </FlexLayout>

        <BoxView Color="Yellow"/>

    </FlexLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

What I got:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEWxN.png)

What I expected:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUCX4.png)

Question says it all.
What I am missing ?

Xamarin Forms 3.2

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2543) may be what is happening here. Seems that inner layouts don't get measured properly.

Answer (score 8):

If you place your child flex layout inside `<ContentView>` it will work:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlexLayout2"
             x:Class="FlexLayout2.MainPage">

    <FlexLayout
        Direction="Column"
        JustifyContent="Start"
        AlignItems="Stretch">
        <ContentView>
            <FlexLayout
                Direction="Row"
                JustifyContent="Start"
                AlignItems="Stretch">
                <BoxView Color="Red"/>
                <BoxView Color="Black"/>
            </FlexLayout>
        </ContentView>
        <BoxView Color="Yellow"/>
    </FlexLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This is the answer, saved me time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the outer FlexLayout sets the height of the inner one to zero if you rely on the default value. Try the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlexLayout2"
             x:Class="FlexLayout2.MainPage">    
    <FlexLayout
        Direction="Column"
        JustifyContent="Start"
        AlignItems="Stretch">
        <FlexLayout HeightRequest="40"
            Direction="Row"
            JustifyContent="Start"
            AlignItems="Stretch">
            <BoxView Color="Red"/>
            <BoxView Color="Black"/>
        </FlexLayout>    
        <BoxView Color="Yellow"/>   
    </FlexLayout>    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Well this works, only thing I can conclude that this is a bug, I tried setting HeightRequest to non zero value on inner FlexLayout childrens and it seems it does not affect inner FlexLayout Height.

Comment: So the code I posted does not resolve your issue? Did I understand your comment correctly

Comment: Your code works as expected. I wanted to see what would happen if set Black and Red BoxView(instead of inner FlexLayout) HeightRequest to non zero value.I was hoping this would affect Inner FlexLayout height so it shows up but this does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue as yours. In case you want to have the `FlexLayout` height to be set automatically, change the first `FlexLayout` to `StackLayout` so your code will be as follow:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
    <FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="Start" AlignItems="Stretch">
        <BoxView Color="Red"/>
        <BoxView Color="Black"/>
    </FlexLayout>
    <BoxView Color="Yellow"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I don't know why it's not working when you have `FlexLayout` inside another `FlexLayout` unless you specify the height of the inner one. May be it's a bug.